Converting hexdump command to Format-Hex
I'm currently having trouble with converting the following command:
echo -ne '\x08\x80\01' | hexdump -C

As of right now, I had a command that worked for the majority of the case (e.g. \x08\x7F works). It looks like this:
$bytes = [byte[]]@(0x08, 0x80, 0x01)
$stdout = [Console]::OutputEncoding.GetString($bytes)
Format-Hex -InputObject $stdout

I simplified the command above. There would be no point of doing the encoding since we could just execute [byte[]]@(0x08, 0x80, 0x01) | Format-Hex. The encoding is done by Powershell here, it comes from the execution of an external command (protoc).
hexdump outputs:
08 80 01

Format-Hex outputs:
08 EF BF BD 01

I assume this is an encoding problem but I can't figure out how to solve it.

What you see is the byte order mark(BOM), you might want to open it in a text editor (even notepad) en save it with a none BOM encoding or save it programmatically with e.g. utf8NoBOM. If you try capturing the (external) command output via the console, you might want ro read: displaying PowerShell output

@iRon I'm pretty sure the BOM comes from protoc. Do you know how can I encode the result of protoc encode without it?

Why do you encode your bytes at all? [byte[]]@(0x08, 0x80, 0x01) | Format-Hex already gives your desired result.

@stackprotector I'm actually using a external command (protoc) to get the bytes and thus Powershell encodes bytes by default...

What are you trying to do, this?  -join [char[]](0x08,0x80,0x01)

protoc is outputing  the 0x08,0x80,0x01 and I want to pipe that to Format-Hex

The output from hexdump 00000000 08 80 01 |...| 00000003 is hexadecimal encoding while the output from Format-Hex 08 EF BF BD 01 is UTF-8 encoding. refer: https://www.charset.org/utf-8

According to your edit history, you want to pipe bytes from a native command to a PowerShell cmdlet (native | ps). Currently, this is not possible1. But you can use a temporary file as a workaround:
# Create a temporary file
$TempFile = New-TemporaryFile

# Write the bytes into the temporary file
Start-Process protoc -ArgumentList "--encode=Encoding ./encoding.proto" -RedirectStandardOutput $TempFile -Wait

# Print a hexdump of the bytes
Format-Hex -Path $TempFile

# (Optional) Remove the temporary file
Remove-Item $TempFile


FYI, with PowerShell 7.4, you are able to pipe bytes from a native command to another native command (native | native).

1 From about_Pipelines:

PowerShell allows you to include native external commands in the pipeline. However, it's important to note that PowerShell's pipeline is object-oriented and doesn't support raw byte data.
Piping or redirecting output from a native program that outputs raw byte data converts the output to .NET strings. This conversion can cause corruption of the raw data output.


This is pretty interesting, however I would like to avoid temporary file... That why I was piping. Is there a way to do what you are doing without that TempFile?

As far as I know, no. FYI, I added a link to the docs, that state the same.
